# NoReverseMatch at /login/

Tags: django, django-urls

NoReverseMatch at /login/ is the error I'm getting from the console, I have a feeling this is something to do with the linking that is going on between urls.py but I can't figure out which part of it is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated on this.

The full error from the console is beneath

```
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' not found. 
'django.contrib.auth.views.login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

### urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls import views as polls_views
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^calendar/', include('calendarium.urls')),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^$', polls_views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': 'login'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^signup/$', polls_views.signup, name='signup'),
]
```

### base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}OnNote{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>My Site</h1>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> / <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
      {% endif %}
      <hr>
    </header>
    <main>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

### login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="content-container" class="container p-none">
        <div class="lgn-container col-lg-8">
            <form id="login-form" method="post" 
                  action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="id_username">Username</label></td>
                        <td><input id="id_username" name="username" 
                                   type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="id_password">Password</label></td>
                        <td><input id="id_password" name="password" 
                                   type="password" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                {% if form.errors %}
                    <p class=" label label-danger">
                        Your username and password didn't match. 
                        Please try again.
                    </p>
                {% endif %}

                <input type="submit" value="Login" 
                       class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? I think it's something to do with my urls.py but I can't figure out what, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The `{% url %}` tag tages the name of a _url pattern_, not the name of a _view function_ and it returns a url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form id="login-form" method="post" action="">
```

in login.html

you dont need the action, simply keeping it to post to itself will work

Answer (score 4):

You can either use form with no action or change `{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}` to `{% url 'login' %}`

By the way, standard login view is deprecated and you will get a warning.
It's better to use `LoginView.as_view()` or subclass it if you want to change the default `template_name` (which is 'registration/login.html').